# Paypal subscriptions not updated

Tags: php, paypal

I have set up a subscription button on my website using the paypal buttons and I have a customer sending me screenshots confirming he has made a payment on the subscriptions but on the recurring payment dashboard there is "no data" and i havent recieved any money on my paypal I got a confirmation in my database that the user was sent to the callback url meaning the payment DID go through so I have no clue what to do I really wanna know where my money is below i attached 2 of the images i recieved
[image: Confirmation 2]

[image: Confirmation1]

Comment: Joseph so what happened?

Comment: For now were letting the customer keep the features and we contacted paypal support havent heard anything back yet

Comment: Ok. Was just wondering what happened because if Paypal fails to report payments I'd want to know also.

Comment: I will let u know once i find out more

Comment: Update @BeetleJuice paypal support got back to me apparently when a user makes a subscription thier "first month" is not billed so the subscription doesnt show up till the next month when thier billed

Comment: Im not sure weather to let my customer keep priveleges untill the payment goes through?

Comment: Thanks for the update; that is useful info. I think you should definitely let this customer keep the privilege, then figure out how you want to handle things going forward.  The customer acted in good faith.

Comment: Well noted I apperciate the help :) @BeetleJuice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pictures are too easy to fake.  Rely on what you see in your own Paypal account.

The customer should have received a transaction number with his Paypal receipt. Have him forward the receipt email to you and try to find the transaction in your account. If it doesn't show up, don't deliver the goods. If you're inclined to believe the customer anyway, talk with Paypal support first.

Either way, don't be confrontational with the customer. Apologize for the delay and reassure him/her that you'll get to the bottom of it. If at the end of the day you don't have the funds, instruct the customer to reach out to Paypal to find out why the money he/she sent wasn't delivered to you.  After all, Paypal cannot give you details of a transaction that is not connected to your account, so you can't resolve it on your own if the transaction doesn't appear in your account.

Comment: my concern seems to be with paypal cause i set the button up with a redirect to a hidden page on my server which sets value to true in my database under his name and when i checked my database the value was true

Comment: That doesn't change my advice. To trick such a system, I would make a legitimate purchase and observe where I'm redirected to, take screenshots of the legitimate payment and then ask for a refund.  Later, I would access the "hidden" page directly (without going through Paypal) with the same request parameters to trigger your DB setting to `true`.  You're probably right and your customer is being honest, but it wouldn't matter to me; if there is a problem with Paypal, we need to resolve it before I can release merchandise.

Comment: Thanks and if he did make a purchase and asked for a refund paypal would/should notify me right? I mean thats just business if someone wants a refund I would like to investigate why

Comment: I don't know whether you'd receive a notification, but I'm sure that the transaction would still appear in your account, with an indication that it was refunded.